# How can I get fast data in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

everyone.
I am working on a python project with selenium to scrape data.
But there is one problem, I have to **scrape** the data every 5mins.
So I run chrome driver with selenium, the problem is selenium **scrape** speed is very slow.
If I run this project, It takes at least 30mins. I can't get data every 5mins.
If you have experience in this field, please help me.
If you can give me other ways(for example beautiful soap), I will be very happy.
Note: This site that I want to get data is rendering using javascript.
This is my source code. I am testing it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(800, 600)

tickerNames = []
finvizUrl = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=exch_nasd,geo_usa,sh_float_u10,sh_price_u10,sh_relvol_o2"
nasdaqUrl = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/"

tickerPrice = []
def openPage(url):
    driver.get(url)

def exitDrive():
    driver.quit()

def getTickers():
    tickers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('screener-link-primary')
    for i in range(len(tickers)):
        tickerNames.append(tickers[i].text)
    return tickerNames

def comparePrice(tickers):
    for i in range(len(tickers)):
        openPage(nasdaqUrl+tickers[i])
        tickerPrice[i] = driver.find_element_by_class_name('symbol-page-header__pricing-price').text
    return tickerPrice
openPage(finvizUrl)
comparePrice(getTickers())
# getTickers()
print(comparePrice())
```

Comment: What happened when you tried using a profiler to determine the bottleneck in the code? What happened when you tried to check whether you are being rate-limited?

Comment: I don't understand your questions.
The problem is to get data every 5mins. but for now, it takes much time(30mins).
I want to get every 5mins.

Comment: Do you have to verify that data via the GUI? No way to do some kind of API GUI-less way calls?

Comment: There is no GUI and API.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use aiosync and aiohttp, populate a set of read tasks that run in parallel.  This is comparatively lightweight and avoids the IO bound timed reads.

Comment: in this case, I agree with your opinion, but when I try to get only 1 data, It also takes about 3~5mins.
I think this is impossible with the selenium way, can I get data using beautiful soap although that site has been rendered by javascript?
If there is way, Please tell me the ways.

Comment: Who have the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an API on the nasdaq site that you can query (found using network tools), so there isn't really any need to use `selenium` for this. Here is an example that gets the data using `requests`

```py
import requests
import lxml.html
import time

FINVIZ_URL = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=exch_nasd,geo_usa,sh_float_u10,sh_price_u10,sh_relvol_o2"
NASDAQ_URL = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/{}/summary?assetclass=stocks"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"
}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

r = session.get(FINVIZ_URL)
# Get data using lxml xpath but use whatever you want
x = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
stocks = x.xpath("//*[@class='screener-link-primary']/text()")

for stock in stocks:
    data = session.get(NASDAQ_URL.format(stock))
    print(f"INFO for {stock}")
    print(data.json())  # This might have the data you want
    # Sleep in case there is a rate limit (may not be needed)
    time.sleep(5)
```